# How to build PJSUA2 (swig) with Visual Studio 2015

Tags: python, sip, voip, pjsua2

I try to compile PJSUA2 for Python. I could manage to compile the source with Visual Studio 2015 Community edition.

My question is, how can I install the Python module now?

The guide suggests to use make and make install. I tried to install also minwg, but it is not working as the project was compiled with VS.

> I have also tried to compile with minwg, but I never could succeed due to undefined requirements. Also official PJSUA guide recommend to use VS for Windows.

Following settings have been applied to build from source:

- Swig location has been added to path
- JAVA_home system variable has been added
- Java location has been added to path
- Empty pjlib/include/pj/config_site.h has been created
- Opened source in VS 2015 Community (all suggested VS package and module has been installed)
- Set following project to do not compile:

  - pjsua_cli_uwp_comp
  - pjsua_cli_wp8
  - pjsua_cli_wp8_comp
- Set swig_java_pjsua2 to build.
- Add following folders to swig_java_pjsua2 VC++ include directories

  - c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\include
  - c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.2\include\win32
- Build solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could make a workaround to compile pjsua2 for Python 3.7. If you have a better solution or just suggestion to this workaround, let me know

Preconditions:

- List item
- Download and extract swig (swigwin 4.0.0)
- Download and install JDK
- Download and install Python (Python 3.7.3 x64) and set at custom  installation:

  - tick "Add Python to environment variables"
  - tick "Precompile standard library"
  - tick "Download debugging symbols"
  - tick "Download debug binaries (requires VS 2015 or later)"
  - set custom path if you want
  - add swigwin location to system path
  - add Python location to system path
  - add JAVA_HOME system variable
  - add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to system path
  - Install Visual Studio 2015 Community edition

Steps:

- Download and extract pjsip 2.8
- Create empty config_site.h under pjlib/inlclude/pj/ folder
- Open pjproject-vs14.sln in VS
- There will be an unsupported warning window, press OK
- At the "Install Missing Features" windows, press install
- VS installer will be started, and VS has to be closed to complete installation.
- I have also added "Windows 10 SDK (10.0.10586)" to the installation.
- I have also enabled developer mode on my Windows 10, but this could be optional
- Open project again in VS
- Set project to Release and x64 on the top dropdown
- Right click on the solution, and go to Configuration Properties> Configuration
- Remove all uwp and wp8 related projects from selection, like pjsua_cli_uwp_comp, pjsua_cli_wp8_comp
- press OK, and build solution
- I have had 34 succeeded and 0 failed solution after build.
- Add following lines to pjsua2.i in pjsip-apps/src/swig folder

  ```
  %inline %{
  pj_ssize_t new_pj_ssize_t(int s) {
     return (pj_ssize_t) s;
  }
  %}
  ```

  > this extra inline swig function provides workaround for create recorder [issue](http://lists.pjsip.org/pipermail/pjsip_lists.pjsip.org/2018-August/041060.html)
- Open a command line (powershell did not work for this)
- go to pjsip-apps/src/swig/python
- Execute following command:

  ```
  swig -I../../../../pjlib/include -I../../../../pjlib-util/include -I../../../../pjmedia/include -I../../../../pjsip/include -I../../../../pjnath/include -py3 -c++  -python -threads ../pjsua2.i
  ```
- Add new "Empty Project" (Visual C++) to solution with swig_python_pjsua2 name
- Add libpjproject and pjsua2_lib as reference to this new project
- Right click on the Header Files>Add>Existing Item...
- Add pjsip-apps\src\swig\pjsua2_wrapp.h
- Add a "new filter" to the project with name "Generated Code"
- Right click on "Generated code" and add new existing item.
- Add pjsip-apps\src\swig\pjsua2_wrapp.cxx
- Right click on the project and Linker>Input
- Add "Ws2_32.Lib" to "Additional Dependencies"
- Go to "VC++ Directories"
- Add following folder to include path(I have used full path!):

  - c:\python37\include
  - pjnath\include
  - pjsip\include
  - pjmedia\include
  - pjlib-util\include
  - pjlib\include
- Add following folder to Library Directories:

  - C:\Python36\libs
- Set at General:

  - Target Name: _$(ProjectName)
  - Target Extension: .pyd
  - Configuration Type: Dynamic Library (.dll)
- Go to properties of the solution, and select swig_python_pjsua2 to build
- Right click on swig_python_pjsua2 and build
- Build should complete successfully
- You will need to file to use pjsua2 library in python.
- pjsua.py located under pjsip-apps/src/swig/python
- x64/Release/_swig_python_pjsua2.pyd (rename this to _pjsua2.pyd)
- To test, copy those to file into a folder, start python from same folder and type:

  - import pjsua2

Answer (score 0):

Thank You very much Krisz for this awesome work!

---

I just got it working for Python 2.7 / 32bit and some things are slightly different, so I will add them here:

### Environment:

- Windows 10
- SWIG 4.0.1
- PJSIP 2.9
- Python 2.7.14 (32bit)
- Visual Studio Express 2015  (V 14.0.25431.01 Update 3)

### Whaddado:

1. Important: Check if your Python-interpreter is really x64 or win32 like the following:
   start a python session and enter:

   > import platform
   >
   > platform.architecture()

   If you have 32bit, consider this in your choice for target platform in VS.
2. when you add this %inline%-Snippet to pjsip-apps/src/swig/pjsua2.i, add it **at the end of the file!**
3. when starting the swig-command, omit the "-py3"-parameter, if you use Python 2.x
4. there is a little typo in Krisz' description, at "pjsua.py located under pjsip-apps/src/swig/python" -> of course pjsua2.py is meant. Do not use the pjsua.py.

finally copy _pjsua2.lib and pjsua2.py into \Lib\site-packages\ and the _pjsua2.pyd into \DLLs\ to make them available everywhere.