# Issue with - PJSUA2 swig with visual studio 2015

Tags: python, windows, swig

After trying Krisz's answer from here:
[How to build PJSUA2 (swig) with Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54882875/how-to-build-pjsua2-swig-with-visual-studio-2015)

I keep getting this error:

```
import pjsua2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\pjsua2.py", line 15, in <module>
    import _pjsua2
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pjsua2: The specified module could not be found.
```

I also tried to copy _pjsua2.lib and pjsua2.py into \Lib\site-packages\ and the _pjsua2.pyd into \DLLs\ to make them available everywhere.

Comment: You might want to use e.g. Dependency Walker (be sure to choose the correct bitness according to your **Python version**, not your OS version) to see what DLLs _pjsua2.pyd needs. https://www.dependencywalker.com/

Comment: Thanks, @AKK, eventually using the new Dependencies tool https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies I found out that a Ws2_32.dll but it was a symptom of misscompiling with the Visual Studio